What does "at the edge" mean in relation to Microsoft Azure?
What does "at the edge" mean in the following statement? I mean, at that edge (close to, near) of what in this context? Thank you!

The Azure cloud platform is more than 200 products and cloud services designed to help you bring new solutions to life—to solve today’s challenges and create the future. Build, run, and manage applications across multiple clouds, on-premises, and at the edge, with the tools and frameworks of your choice.

Azure home page

At the "edge" between "On premises" and "in the cloud".

@FreeMan e.g. if you have a smart meter and you want daily totals you can either run the totalling on the meter or on a server. If it is on the meter, then that is 'on the edge', if it is on your server then that is either 'on premises' or 'in the cloud' depending where the server is.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_computing

Edge computing, or computing done at the edge, is an IT (information technology) term. The 'edge' is the notional periphery or boundary of a computer network with data centres at the central point.
Edge computing is a distributed IT architecture in which client data is processed at the periphery of the network, as close to the originating source as possible.
Instead of transmitting raw data to a central data centre for processing and analysis, that work is instead performed where the data is actually generated, e.g. on board a vehicle such as a bus train, or plane, in a retail store, a factory floor, a public utility or across a smart city. Only the result of that computing work at the edge, such as real-time business information, vehicle maintenance predictions, etc, is sent back to the main data centre for review by humans. Advantages include reduced network/Internet congestion, faster response for users, less reliance on single data processing centres.

This is IT jargon.
"Edge" computing is another option alongside 'cloud' (storage and/or processing on remote internet servers) and 'on premises' (physical servers on your site) computing.
As I understand it, 'edge' computing is where you have a physical server or storage area network located near to your premises, but not actually on it and not completely remote. Note that the concept of the server being "on the edge" refers to the network topology and not necessarily physical location. Also note though that I am simplifying because this is an English learners site and not an IT technical site. You might get a better explanation of the term on an appropriate site.
